# Linq always return last record

Tags: vb.net, linq

I successfully get the list of the record but the problem is the last record always override the first record. The record count already correct. Here are my codes. Please help. Thanks.

```
Private Function MyFunction(ByVal myList As List(Of TT_GENERAL_CONFIGURATION))
        Dim pConfig As New Config
        Dim lst As New List(Of Config)

        For Each MyCls As TT_GENERAL_CONFIGURATION In myList
            pConfig.ConfigID = MyCls.INTERNAL_NUM
            pConfig.ConfigType = MyCls.CONFIG_TYPE
            pConfig.ConfigName = MyCls.CONFIG_NAME
            pConfig.ConfigValue = MyCls.CONFIG_VALUE

            lst.Add(pConfig)
        Next

        Return lst
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you're reusing the same reference to an object which means you're not actually adding new objects but rather new references to the same object. Your code should look like the following (the initialization of "Config" type is moved inside the loop):

```
Private Function MyFunction(ByVal myList As List(Of TT_GENERAL_CONFIGURATION))
        Dim pConfig As Config
        Dim lst As New List(Of Config)

        For Each MyCls As TT_GENERAL_CONFIGURATION In myList
            pConfig = New Config()

            pConfig.ConfigID = MyCls.INTERNAL_NUM
            pConfig.ConfigType = MyCls.CONFIG_TYPE
            pConfig.ConfigName = MyCls.CONFIG_NAME
            pConfig.ConfigValue = MyCls.CONFIG_VALUE

            lst.Add(pConfig)
        Next

        Return lst
End Function
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Currently you create single config instance and add it many times to your list. On each loop you only modify values of this single config object. Move config creation inside the loop:

```
Private Function MyFunction(ByVal myList As List(Of TT_GENERAL_CONFIGURATION)) 
    Dim lst As New List(Of Config)

    For Each MyCls As TT_GENERAL_CONFIGURATION In myList
        Dim pConfig As New Config
        pConfig.ConfigID = MyCls.INTERNAL_NUM
        pConfig.ConfigType = MyCls.CONFIG_TYPE
        pConfig.ConfigName = MyCls.CONFIG_NAME
        pConfig.ConfigValue = MyCls.CONFIG_VALUE

        lst.Add(pConfig)
    Next

    Return lst
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

you are instanciating `pConfig` only one time, and then in you loop you are modifying it over and over again move the instanciation eithin the loop.